# Active blogs about Lazarus and/or FPC

Tags: resources, twitter, blogs, lazarus, fpc

I'm getting really upset with the whole direction that "Emborcadero" is taking and I'm really going to invest in FPC/Lazarus.

Went to the [Lazarus Documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Documentation) page and found the following blogs:

- [Lazarus Development](http://lazarus-dev.blogspot.com/) - Up to date
- [Adventures of a Newbie](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Adventures_of_a_Newbie) - FPC Wiki page
- [On the road with Lazarus/Free Pascal](http://lazarusroad.blogspot.com/) - Up to date
- [Porting to Lazarus](http://port2laz.blogspot.com/) - Last post December 2009
- [Living Lazarus](http://living-lazarus.blogspot.com/) - Last post September 2009
- [Parallel Pascal Worlds](http://donaldshimoda.blogspot.com/) - Up to date

Can someone suggest more resources in terms of Blogs or Twitter accounts to follow?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into

- [FPC and Delphi: toward a "fratricidal war"?](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/08/14/FPC-and-Delphi:-toward-a-%22fratricidal-war%22)

But I don't like the tone. While it is true that the absence of colaboration between FPC and Delphi leads to incompatibilities in the newest features, I think he makes a too big deal out of it.

Moreover, most people that chose for FPC/Lazarus do so because they are needing some real features of FPC/Lazarus that Delphi doesn't provide or plans to provide. It is rarely a one dimensional "Lazarus is free" choice.

- like e.g. native interfacing with OS X, while Embarcadero only prepares a QT port),
- ARM/PowerPC/Sparc support etc.

Comment: Thanks Marco!

As usual you're the guy that kinda gives the most support to the FPC/Lazarus questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Well, there are some blogposts by user leledumbo from the lazarus forum](http://pascalgeek.blogspot.com/)